# Angular 6 scroll to top on some views

Tags: angular

I have this issue with my **Angular** 6 application.
When navigating between pages, it loads the position of the previous page.
I know you can do something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
})
export class MyAppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
            if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
                return;
            }
            window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        });
    }
}
```

Which will scroll to the top on all page transitions. My issue is that in some cases, I don't want it to do that. Specifically I have 3 views that do not want to scroll: **questions**, **answers** and **results**.

So, I tried to fix this by doing this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID, Inject, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RoutesRecognized, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'pyb-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private widgetUrls: any[] = ['questions', 'answers', 'results']
    private url: string

    private routeSubscription: Subscription

    constructor(
        private route: Router,
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.routeSubscription = this.route.events.subscribe(event => {
            this.getCurrentUrl(event);
            this.scrollToTop(event);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.routeSubscription) this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    private scrollToTop(event: any): void {
        if (event! instanceof NavigationEnd) return;
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) return;

        let scroll = this.shouldScroll();
        if (!scroll) return;

        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    private shouldScroll(): boolean {
        if (!this.url) return true;

        let urlSegments = this.url.split('/');
        if (urlSegments.length === 1) return true;

        let lastSegment = urlSegments[urlSegments.length - 1];
        let index = this.widgetUrls.indexOf(lastSegment);

        return index === -1; // Only scroll if we are not on the widget
    }

    private getCurrentUrl(event: any): void {
        if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
            this.url = event.url;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work; but sometimes it seems to not realise which view I am on and there doesn't work :/
Does anyone know if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: which version of angular are you using

Comment: 6 :d I will update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using angular 6+

**ViewportScroller**

ViewportScroller is a new feature that allows us to use the scroll value.

```
 import { ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common';

 constructor(private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) { }
 private scrollToTop(event: any): void {
        if (event! instanceof NavigationEnd) return;
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) return;

        let scroll = this.shouldScroll();
        if (!scroll) return;

        this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
    }
```

Ref:https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller

Comment: Can you please add some more information on this ? I just want to learn more on this ... :)

Comment: @SachinShah please check: https://medium.com/@sarunint/scroll-position-restoration-in-angular-5a09df8bf626

Comment: Thanks for sharing