# How can I scroll to an anchor in my angular page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, anchor

I want to create anchor in my angular page but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

My html component :

```
<h1 id="choose_package">Step 1 : choose a package</h1>
<div>Some elements</div>
<a [href]="choose_package">test</a>
```

But it return me null and go to 404 page.

Edit (now I can scroll but it's not done little by little):

```
this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof Scroll)).subscribe((e: any) => {
    if (e.position) {
      this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
    } else if (e.anchor) {
      this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
    } else {
      this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
    }
  ;
});
```

Comment: Can you try `<a [href]="'#choose_package'">test</a>` ?

Comment: Hi, when I try this I'm redirect to homepage

Answer (score 0):

Anchor Scrolling are disabled by default at v6.1.0.
 Enable the anchor scrolling inside the route configuration

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Then use fragment

```
<h1 id="choose_package">Step 1 : choose a package for your license</h1>
<div>Some elements</div>
<a [fragment]="choose_package">test</a>
```

Comment: Check this exmaple https://stackblitz.com/edit/dvl-ng-router-anchorscrolling?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have the same error : 
Unable to assign type '{anchorScrolling: string; scrollPositionRestoration: string; } 'to type' ExtraOptions'.
  An object literal can only specify known properties, and 'anchorScrolling' does not exist in the 'ExtraOptions' type.

Comment: Cab you check the Angular version

Comment: Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.6

Comment: I have mentioned it wil only work in angular 6.1. And don't  use href it will load the page.

Comment: Hm, I have an error : Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'fragment' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Comment: Is choose_package simple string or property?

Comment: it's a simple string

Comment: Try this [fragment]="'choose_package'"

Comment: Cab you create stackblitz if it possible

Comment: if you want to scroll to top then i suggest you to check this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805045/angular-6-scroll-to-top-on-some-views/53805270#53805270

Comment: Your stackblitz is not working because you have not added router-outlet and routerlink directive

Answer (score 0):

use Fragment to do it.

```
<h1 id="choose_package">
Step 1 : choose a package for your license
</h1>
<div>Some elements</div>
<a [fragment]="choose_package">test</a>
```

It will redirect to "choose_package" on the same page.

You also need to define in your rootModule the `anchorScrolling`

```
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    })
  ]
})
...
```

Comment: Hi, I have the error : Unable to assign type '{anchorScrolling: string; scrollPositionRestoration: string; } 'to type' ExtraOptions'. An object literal can only specify known properties, and 'anchorScrolling' does not exist in the 'ExtraOptions' type.